# Unable to query data from SQL Server using Golang - Getting error "Invalid object name"

Tags: sql-server, go, go-gorm

I am trying to query data from SQL Server using Golang and GORM. But I am getting below error:-

```
DB Connection: &{{{0 0} 0 0 0 0} <nil> <nil> 0 0xc0000a4480 false 0 {0xc0000e5db0} <nil> {{0 0} {<nil>} map[] 0} 0xc00004c5b0 0xaccbe0 0xc00014d0a0 false <nil>}

HasTable- Currency: true
{CurrencyId:0 Code: Description:}

[35m(C:/Users/RahulBFL/Documents/architechbc/dot net/GORM/main.go:26)[0m
[33m[2019-12-27 15:56:13][0m [31;1m mssql: Invalid object name 'currencies'. [0m
```

My Table Schema looks like below:-

```
     Currency
CurrencyId    int
Code          char
Description   varchar
```

On SSMS, I am successfully able to query the table using the below command

```
select * from IMBookingApp.dbo.Currency
```

My Golang code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/jinzhu/gorm"
    _ "github.com/jinzhu/gorm/dialects/mssql"
)

type Currency struct {
    CurrencyId  int
    Code        string
    Description string
}

func main() {

    db, err := gorm.Open("mssql", "sqlserver://USERNAME:PASSWORD@Endpoint:1433?database=DATABASENAME&Initial+Catalog=SCHEMA_NAME")

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Connection Error:", err)
    }

   fmt.Println("DB Connection", db)


    fmt.Println("HasTable- Currency:", db.HasTable("ClientUser"))

    var Currency Currency
    db.Find(&Currency)

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", Currency)

    defer db.Close()
}
```

I don't understand why I am getting the error as  - Invalid object name 'currencies'. Though there is no **currencies** in the schema, there is only **currency**.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check your error `Invalid object name 'currencies'` it tries to find table named `currencies`. By default gorm pluralizes tables names. If you want a custom table name you can define it like below :

```
func (Currency) TableName() string {
    return "currency"
}
```

Or you can globally disable it with :

```
db.SingularTable(true)
```

So you sample should look like this :

```
type Currency struct {
    CurrencyId  int
    Code        string
    Description string
    CreateDate  time.Time
}

func (Currency) TableName() string {
    return "currency"
}


func main() {
    db, err := gorm.Open("mssql", "sqls*******talog=dbo")

    db.SingularTable(true)

    fmt.Println("db.HasTable: Currency:", db.HasTable("ClientUser"))

    var Currency []Currency 

    db.Find(&Currency)

    ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. After adding `db.SingularTable(true)`, this error is resolved - `Invalid object name 'currencies'`. However, I am not getting any rows in the response.

Comment: @RahulSatal find may expect an array to be passed. Find will find all objects in the table. You can try using `first` method or pass an array of `Currency`

Comment: After using the function `TableName`. I am getting another error - `unsupported destination, should be slice or struct.` I may not be using the function correctly. You can see my code here - https://play.golang.org/p/g9fwRcq-pQw

Comment: Thanks for the code. However, from the above code I am getting empty string with no error as - `[{CurrencyId:0 Code: Description: CreateDate:0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC}]`

Comment: Also, with `var Currency Currency` and `db.First(&Currency)` . I am getting this error - `mssql: Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement.`

Comment: When I add some options like ` db.First(&Currency).Order("Code").Limit(2).Offset(0)` I don't get any error, but still the response is empty.

Comment: @RahulSatal For `first` method gorm has an unresolved [issue](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm/issues/1205). As SQL server expects and order by phrase to make fetch work. And try to log sql query generated by gorm and execute query somewhere else (Visualstudio or SSMS) see how it results

Comment: Using `First` with debug I am getting this query - `SELECT * FROM [currency]  OFFSET 0 LIMIT 1 ROWS FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY` which is invalid on SSMS and giving same error as - `Invalid usage of the option NEXT in the FETCH statement.`

Comment: Using `db.Debug().Find(&Currency)` I am getting this output `[1 rows affected or returned ]` . However again the response is empty. Any clue?

Comment: @RahulSatal After making my own tests i managed to reproduce your issues. It seems gorm fails to throw the right exception. The case you are having occurs when your property names don't match the database exactly. Check your property names or  use annotations to configure your property names : `type User struct { 
 Mail string` `gorm:"column:EMail"`
}`

Comment: Yes, It is always creating the wrong SQL statement. It is creating `SELECT * FROM [currency]` but it should be `SELECT * FROM IMBookingApp.dbo.currency`. I am quitting from GORM. I will manually use the `"database/sql"` package. Thanks for your help @Eldar.

Comment: @rahul `gorm.DefaultTableNameHandler = func(dbVeiculosGorm *gorm.DB, defaultTableName string) string {
    return "your schema name." + defaultTableName
}` you can use this function to manually set your schema